# SQL Querying Help/IF Conditional Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am creating a booking table. I have two drop down lists called Date and Time and the data for these is being retrieved from a table called "DateTime" with a field called Date with a load of dates in it and same with time.

This booking system is booking time and a date with a Doctor. I'm lost at this point in terms of how do I get times to only appear for a doctor that the user wants to choose an appointment with to avoid double bookings. If a user has booked 9:15am on a certain date, I don't want that time to appear for another user for that date and doctor.

*UPDATE* Once a user has selected their date time and doctor, this is stored in a table called Booking. So i was originally going to delete that time and date out of that DateTime but this will then  not appear for another doctor if selected.

HELP PLEASE. :'(

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a query without deleting data from your DateTime table.

```
    SELECT dt.[Date], dt.[Time], dt.Doctor
    FROM dbo.[DateTime] dt
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1
                        FROM dbo.Booking b
                        WHERE 
                            b.[Date] = dt.[Date]
                            AND b.[Time] = dt.[Time]
                            AND b.Doctor = dt.Doctor)
```

The query selects all the dates and times that does not currently exist in your booking table.

Hope this helps.

Marius

Comment: Thanks for this! Before I try this, can you explain fully what this does? Does this solve my problem on avoiding double bookings? As in for example If I book 9am for one doctor on a certain date, that time will be there if it isn't booked for another doctor on that date? Sorry for lack of code to show but can do this tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Shannen.  Just want to verify my understanding.  You have one table, DateTime, that contains a list of dates and times of possible appointments.  For a booking, a user will select the date, time and doctor which is then stored in the Booking table.  Once a booking is made for 1 Jan 2017 with Doc A, is it possible to make another appointment at the same date and time, but for a different doctor?

Comment: Hi Marius, Yes that's correct. I've tried to play about with my code but getting nowhere :/ Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also, the doctor is coming from another table called Doctor and this table has a list of doctors and their common details.

Comment: I suggest you add the doctor to the DateTime table.  That will allow you to add different times for different doctors.  I'll update my query to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

At least you should share your own table design.

I think there will be two table.

One Master table (booking master table)
--date
--time
--isactive

Another one

doctor booking table

--date
--time
--doctorid
--patientid
--isActive (0,1)-- 0 in cae of cancel

So in GUI I select Doctor and Date,I pass this doctorid and date to my proc

It fetch me date,time etc from proc.which help me to populate calender.
I populate calender for each doctorid and date.
So I have written this on doctor and date change both.

Now while creating Calendar,if I get already book flag then I will show this time,but it will be disable.

My query will be like this

```
select bm.date,bm.time
,case when db.date=dbm.date then 1 else 0 end isBookedDate
from BookingMaster BM
left join DoctorBookingMapping DBM
on bm.date=dbm.date
where dbm.isactive=1
and db.isactive=1
and dbm.doctorid=@Doctorid
and db.date=@Date
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this. I'm still confused tbh. If I showed you code would it help? I have two tables one called DateTime with two fields in on it date and time and then a booking table which contains all the bookings for appointments with doctors

Comment: @ShannenLyons , little advice.Just start .Start from GUI design ,code etc. and ask where you are struck.